# how to pass hidden field values in MVC route object in BeginForm

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a textbox and a button as shown below. In the hdnCityAreaService I am setting Id of the item that user will be selecting in angular typeahead textbox inside `callBack($item,$model,$label)` from js.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestAction", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, 
  new { strTest = "@hdnCityAreaService.value to be passed here" }))
  { 
    <div data-ng-app="v">
      <div ng-controller="TypeAheadController">
        <input type="text" id="txtType" ng-model="selected" typeahead-on-select="callBack($item,$model,$label)" typeahead="state as state.Name for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
        @Html.Hidden("hdnCityAreaService")
        <input type="submit" id="sub" name="sub" value="click"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  }
```

My TestAction looks like:

```
public ActionResult TestAction(string strTest)
{
  return View();
}
```

I want to send the value of "hdnCityAreaService" route value object so that it will appear at strTest parameter in Action. How can I do this besides using FormCollection?

Comment: Then name it correctly `@Html.Hidden("strTest")` and delete it from the route values.

Comment: why are you calling it "route value"? `@Html.Hidden("strTest", "@hdnCityAreaService")`

Comment: @Igor what is it called? I am new to MVC. Also can you please provide an example? because if you are suggesting that I should declare hiddne field as @Html.Hidden("strTest", "@hdnCityAreaService") then in the strTest parameter of TestAction I am getting only "@hdnCityAreaService" irrespective of any thing.

Comment: Did you remove it from the route parameter in the `Html.BeginForm` method? The route values take precedence over the form values so it will always return the initial value of `@hdnCityAreaService` if you don't remove it.

Comment: what about you model?

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke you have confused me now. After removing it from Html.BeginForm and renaming parameter of TestAction, value was present. but can you please modify the answer below so that I will know what you are saying?

Comment: @Mikhail, the view is not bound to any model.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad, What you have shown in your answer will work fine. The issue with your question code was that you generated a route parameter in the `Html.BeginForm` method named `strTest`. `Html.BeginForm` is razor code which is parsed on the server so the value of `strTest` was already set before it was sent to the view (check the html of the `<form>` tag) so the value you got in the `TestAction` method was always its initial value. Just changing the input name to `strTest` would not be enough since the route value takes precedence.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Got it. thank you for the explanation. but how did it work when I just changed the name of input parameter to the name of hidden field? and as you said route values take precedence, then how  can I pass the hidden field value using route values?

Comment: Yes, but the route parameter name was `strTest` and your previous parameter was `strTest` so on post back the parameter value would be taken from the (fixed) route value. Now you have a parameter named `hdnCityAreaService` which matches the input name. If you kept the route parameter and change the method to `TestAction(string hdnCityAreaService, string strTest)` you would see both values posted back. By 'take precedence', I mean if you have a route parameter and an input with the same name, the route parameter will take precedence (the form value will be ignored)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified the code as below per  Stephen Muecke suggestion:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestAction", "Customer", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
<div data-ng-app="v">
    <div ng-controller="TypeAheadController">
        <input type="text" id="txtType" ng-model="selected" typeahead-on-select="callBack($item,$model,$label)" typeahead="state as state.Name for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
        @Html.Hidden("hdnCityAreaService")
        <input type="submit" id="sub" name="sub" value="click"/>
    </div>
</div>
}

public void TestAction(string hdnCityAreaService)
        {
            ReturnView();
        }
```